# What prevents wp_enqueue_script inside a loop_start

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

The `wp_enqueue_script` operates fine as a stand alone script in the main function file. However, when this is placed inside a `loop_start` function (isolated to run on a specific page), the javascript it calls does not load. Both the 'page name' and post ID work in `is_page( )` validated by `$message`.

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'run_on_config_page' );    
function run_on_config_page() {    
  if ( is_page( 1885 ) ) {      
    function config_scripts() {        
      wp_enqueue_script( 'config_scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js', array( 'jquery' ) , '0.0.1', time(), true );        
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'config_scripts' );    
//    $message = "Load Script Here";    
//      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";    
  }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. Use this code to fulfill your requirement.

```
function config_scripts() {
 if( is_page( 1885 ) ){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'config_scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js', array( 'jquery' ) , '0.0.1', time(), true );
  }} 
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'config_scripts' );
```